# UI Scaling issues only with QHD and 4k UHD

Tags: unity, unity-ui

I have a card game, where I'd like to be able to zoom in on a card if it's right clicked. I coded to make sure that if the zoomed card would go over a screen boundary, instead we would anchor it such that the full card is displayed. I initially hardcoded everything for 1920x1080 resolution, then I wanted to get it to work for an arbitrary resolution. The logic seems to work for all resolutions except for `QHD` and `4k UHD`.

I feel like I have a fundamental misunderstanding of resolutions, or I'm missing something with either how `RectTransform` scaling works, or how the units for width/height correspond to resolutions, or how the interaction between `Canvas` and `CanvasScaler` work with resolutions. The math seems simple, but it's not working for these resolutions, so I'm obviously missing something.

For reference:

[image: Canvas Settings]

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class Zoomable : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler, IPointerUpHandler
{
    private GameObject _popOutCard;
    private bool _enabled;

    // Works for all resolutions except QHD and 4k UHD.
    // Calculations: Card Dimensions are 150 x 200.
    // So, if we're, for example, scaling by a factor of 2, the zoomed cards are 300 x 400.
    // We're using the (x,y) coordinates of the cursor.
    // So for 1920 x 1080, for example:
    // To display a zoomed card, its center with respect to x can never be less than 155 (300/2, with an offset of 5).
    // The same logic is applied to the other 3 boundaries.

    private const int _offset = 5;
    private const int _cardHeightHalfed = 100;
    private const int _cardWidthHalfed = 75;

    private float _topBoundary;
    private float _bottomBoundary;
    private float _leftBoundary;
    private float _rightBoundary;

    [SerializeField]
    private float _scaleFactor = 2.5f;

    private Transform _canvasTransform;

    void Awake()
    {
        // We're mixing ints and floats here, but it's fine.
        _canvasTransform = transform.root;
        _topBoundary = Screen.height - _scaleFactor * _cardHeightHalfed - _offset;
        _bottomBoundary =_scaleFactor * _cardHeightHalfed + _offset;
        _leftBoundary = _scaleFactor * _cardWidthHalfed + _offset;
        _rightBoundary = Screen.width - _scaleFactor * _cardWidthHalfed - _offset;
        var resolution = Screen.currentResolution;

        Debug.Log($"Resolution height: {resolution.height}, resolution width: {resolution.width}");
        Debug.Log($"Screen height: {Screen.height}, resolution width: {Screen.width}");
    }
    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        if (eventData.button == PointerEventData.InputButton.Right)
        {
            ZoomPopOut();
        }
    }

    public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log("OnPointerUp called");
        if (_enabled)
        {
            OnZoomPopOutExit();
        }
    }

    private void ZoomPopOut()
    {
        float xPosition = Input.mousePosition.x;
        float yPosition = Input.mousePosition.y;
        Debug.Log($"x position: {xPosition}, y position: {yPosition}");

        float popOutXPosition = xPosition;
        float popOutYPosition = yPosition;

        if (xPosition < _leftBoundary)
        {
            popOutXPosition = _leftBoundary;
        }

        if (xPosition > _rightBoundary)
        {
            popOutXPosition = _rightBoundary;
        }

        if (yPosition < _bottomBoundary)
        {
            popOutYPosition = _bottomBoundary;
        }

        if (yPosition > _topBoundary)
        {
            popOutYPosition = _topBoundary;
        }

        Debug.Log($"Pop out x position: {popOutXPosition}, pop out y position: {popOutYPosition}");

        _popOutCard = Instantiate(gameObject, new Vector2(popOutXPosition, popOutYPosition), Quaternion.identity);
        _popOutCard.transform.SetParent(_canvasTransform);
        _popOutCard.transform.SetAsLastSibling();

        RectTransform rect = _popOutCard.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
        rect.localScale = new Vector3(_scaleFactor, _scaleFactor, _scaleFactor);
        _enabled = true;
    }

    private void OnZoomPopOutExit()
    {
        Debug.Log("OnZoomPopOutExit() called");
        _enabled = false;
        Destroy(_popOutCard);
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're computing your positions in the coordinate system of the screen (which changes with screen resolution), not in the coordinate system of the canvas (which you've set to maintain its own scale factor relative to the screen, using the Canvas Scaler component). Did you mean to use [ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle.html) to convert between these two coordinate systems?

Comment: @DMGregory I am using the coordinate system of the screen, but I assumed that using Screen.height and Screen.width in my top and right boundary calculations would account for the changes in resolution? Does it not? I feel like I'm missing something here...

Comment: I tried this, but it did not seem to work, perhaps I'm misunderstanding the API:

var success = RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle(_canvasTransform.GetComponent<RectTransform>(), new Vector2(popOutXPosition, popOutYPosition), null, out convertedPosition);
        _popOutCard = Instantiate(gameObject, convertedPosition, Quaternion.identity);

Comment: Remember to set the (local or anchored) position after assigning the parent, or use WorldPositionStays = false. If you need further clarification, edit your question to show your updated code.

Comment: "Screen.height and Screen.width in my top and right boundary calculations would account for the changes in resolution" in screen space, yes. But canvas space isn't screen space - it's scaled up to fit, so the internal space is smaller than that.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```cs
RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle(
    (RectTransform)_canvasTransform,
    new Vector2(popOutXPosition, popOutYPosition), 
    null, // If not using Screen Space - Overlay, provide a camera here.
    out var convertedPosition
);

// Set the parent first.
_popOutCard = Instantiate(gameObject, _canvasTransform);

// THEN set the position WITHIN that parent.
_popOutCard.transform.localPosition = convertedPosition;

// For some UI setups you may prefer to use anchoredPosition.

_popOutCard.transform.localScale = Vector3.one * _scaleFactor;
_enabled = true;
```

Comment: I understand what you're saying now. My mental model was a bit off. This code makes sense to me; however, I'm still getting that same results. I tried anchoredPosition as well. The mapping from screen space to canvas space is successful; however, the cards are still going off the screen, which is super confusing.

Comment: We might need more details about your setup then. Can you edit your question to include a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example?

Comment: Good idea. I'm not at a computer right now, but I'll edit it later tonight or tomorrow with a complete example.

Comment: Thank you for the help. `RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle` was exactly what I needed, but I had to modify the code a bit. I updated my question with the solution, but am accepting your answer since it's essentially correct and 100% got me to my solution.

Comment: Please post your solution as an Answer, not as an edit to the question. I've got all the rep I need, so you can mark your 100% working answer as Accepted (after a short delay) — that gives a better hint to future readers looking for a quick fix.

Comment: Thanks again, done.

Comment: No worries, I'm glad you got it working!

Answer (score 1):

I didn't realize that I needed to map from screen space (mouse coordinates) to canvas space in my original code. After learning about `RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle` and realizing that `Instantiate` always anchors to the center of the canvas, I also realized that I should modify the border calculations to account for the anchoring, and move the constraining borders code to after the screen space to canvas space mapping.

````
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class Zoomable : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler, IPointerUpHandler
{
    private GameObject _popOutCard;
    private bool _enabled;

    // Mouse Coordinates are given in screen space.
    // We then map those coordinates to canvas space, which is set to
    // 1920 x 1080.
    // Calculations: Card Dimensions are 150 x 200.
    // So, if we're, for example, scaling by a factor of 2, the zoomed cards are 300 x 400.
    // So for 1920 x 1080:
    // To display a zoomed card, its center with respect to x can never be less than 155 (300/2, with an offset of 5) away
    // from a left/right boundary.
    // The same logic is applied to the top/bottom boundaries.
    // Since the anchoring of the popOutCard with respect to the canvas is centered, i.e. (0,0) is the center of the canvas
    // we need to account for that when calculating the boundaries in Awake.

    private const int _offset = 5;
    private const int _cardHeightHalfed = 100;
    private const int _cardWidthHalfed = 75;
    private const int _canvasHeightHalfed = 540;
    private const int _canvasWidthHalfed = 960;

    private float _topBoundaryCanvas;
    private float _bottomBoundaryCanvas;
    private float _leftBoundaryCanvas;
    private float _rightBoundaryCanvas;


    [SerializeField]
    private float _scaleFactor = 2.5f;

    private Transform _canvasTransform;

    void Awake()
    {
        _canvasTransform = transform.root;

        // We're mixing ints and floats here, but it's fine.
        _topBoundaryCanvas = (_canvasHeightHalfed - _scaleFactor * _cardHeightHalfed - _offset);
        _bottomBoundaryCanvas = (_canvasHeightHalfed - _scaleFactor * _cardHeightHalfed - _offset)*-1;
        _leftBoundaryCanvas = (_canvasWidthHalfed - _scaleFactor * _cardWidthHalfed + _offset)*-1;
        _rightBoundaryCanvas = _canvasWidthHalfed - _scaleFactor * _cardWidthHalfed - _offset;
    }

    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        if (eventData.button == PointerEventData.InputButton.Right)
        {
            ZoomPopOut();
        }
    }

    public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log("OnPointerUp called");
        if (_enabled)
        {
            OnZoomPopOutExit();
        }
    }

    private void ZoomPopOut()
    {
        float xPosition = Input.mousePosition.x;
        float yPosition = Input.mousePosition.y;
        Debug.Log($"x position: {xPosition}, y position: {yPosition}");

        Vector2 convertedPosition;
        RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle((RectTransform)_canvasTransform,
                                                                new Vector2(xPosition, yPosition), 
                                                                null,
                                                                out convertedPosition);

        Debug.Log($"Pop out x position: {convertedPosition.x}, pop out y position: {convertedPosition.y} in canvas space");

        if (convertedPosition.x < _leftBoundaryCanvas)
        {
            convertedPosition.x = _leftBoundaryCanvas;
        }

        if (convertedPosition.x > _rightBoundaryCanvas)
        {
            convertedPosition.x = _rightBoundaryCanvas;
        }

        if (convertedPosition.y < _bottomBoundaryCanvas)
        {
            convertedPosition.y = _bottomBoundaryCanvas;
        }

        if (convertedPosition.y > _topBoundaryCanvas)
        {
            convertedPosition.y = _topBoundaryCanvas;
        }


        Debug.Log($"Pop out x constrained: {convertedPosition.x}, pop out y constrained: {convertedPosition.y} in canvas space");

        _popOutCard = Instantiate(gameObject, _canvasTransform);
        _popOutCard.transform.localPosition = convertedPosition;
        _popOutCard.transform.localScale = Vector3.one * _scaleFactor;
        _enabled = true;
    }

    private void OnZoomPopOutExit()
    {
        Debug.Log("OnZoomPopOutExit() called");
        _enabled = false;
        Destroy(_popOutCard);
    }
}

```
````